# code for bootstrap active nav not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

please i have been trying to get this code to add class active to my nav li element but it doesnt work.

Home

```
    <li  id="orange">
                <a href="hotels.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bed icondeco"></span>Hotel</a>
            </li> 
            <li  id="blue">
                <a href="flights.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plane icondeco"></span>Flight</a>
            </li> 
             <li  id='red'>
                <a href="cars.php"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star icondeco"></span>cars</a>
            </li>

            <li  id='green'>
                <a href="visas.php"> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-tags icondeco'></span>Visas</a>
            </li>


            <li  id='plum'>
                <a href="vacation.php"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart icondeco'></span>Vacations</a>
            </li>

            <li  id='purple'>
                <a href="corporate.php"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase icondeco'></span>Corporate</a>
            </li>

         </ul>
```

// i have this code at the bottom of the body of my page

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

 <script>


     $('.nav li').click(function(){
    $('.nav li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.nav li').click(function(){
$(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Comment: thank you , i tried this and it still isnt working. any ideas?

Comment: you have href attributes on a elements. so you can't use this code. I just answered your question.

Comment: so how can i do this please. if you could post a code that works it will be great

Comment: @PearlIsa you need to prevent default.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal how do i do this please, if you could expatiate that would be great

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `active` class in al list and removing the class in all lists. Thus, you need to use `$(this)` to add `active` class to your currently clicked list and remove all siblings list class:

```
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
//^^ instead of $('.nav li')
```

Comment: thank you, but i did this and it is still not working

Comment: <!-- jQuery -->
     <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    
     <script>
      $('.nav li').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
})
    </script>